# How to Copy Data from One Google Sheet to Another Sheet at the next blank row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I am not much familiar with Google Sheet. I am using a template from the Internet to make it usable after view the youtube videos. Here is the link to my Google Sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KD_qFT6J6ife72OhQRzr0pHSiyyRNA3X8KCDTc2A-iE/edit?usp=sharing

What I am doing.
1- I copy data from finance and paste it into the History Tab.
2- Then I filter data according to the tab name like "BNB", "BTC", etc. and paste particular filter data in that particular sheet.
It is really time taking work and makes me tired. I want to automate the entire process, just click the button "Populate Data" and data should be populated in all the sheets automatically. Is it possible to do this? If yes then please guide me on how to do it? Thanks

Comment: can anyone suggest to me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task looks pretty easy. As a simplest naive solution you can try to extend this example:

```
function copy_rows_from_history() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // get data from 'History1'
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('History1');
  var data = s.getRange(1,1,s.getLastRow(),8).getDisplayValues();

  // get all XPR rows from the data
  var XRP = data.filter(x => x[1] == 'XRPUSDT');

  // add the XPR rows to the 'XPR' sheet
  s = ss.getSheetByName('XRP');
  var lastRow = s.getRange('A1:A').getValues().filter(String).length;
  s.getRange(lastRow+1,1,XRP.length,XRP[0].length).setValues(XRP);

  // get all SHIB rows from the data
  var SHIB = data.filter(x => x[1] == 'SHIBUSDT');

  // add the SHIB rows to the 'SHIB' sheet
  s = ss.getSheetByName('SHIB');
  var lastRow = s.getRange('A1:A').getValues().filter(String).length;
  s.getRange(lastRow+1,1,SHIB.length,SHIB[0].length).setValues(SHIB);

  // etc...
}
```

Of course it would be more efficient to replace these 'XPR', 'SHIB', etc. with some array (dynamically created from the values of 2nd column of the 'History1' sheet) and loop trough this array with a couple universal functions. Etc. But I'm not sure if you ready to dive so deep in JS coding? Sometimes the simper the better.

Full-fledged variant of the script is here:

```
function copy_rows_from_history() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // make the object with short and full names all the markets
  const MARKETS = {};

  [ 
    ['ADAUSDT'  , 'ADA'  ], ['BNBUSDT'  , 'BNB'  ], ['BTCUSDT'  , 'BTC'  ], ['BTTUSDT'  , 'BTT'  ],
    ['CELRUSDT' , 'CELR' ], ['DENTUSDT' , 'DENT' ], ['DOGEUSDT' , 'DOGE' ], ['EOSUSDT'  , 'EOS'  ],
    ['ETHUSDT'  , 'ETH'  ], ['FTMUSDT'  , 'FTM'  ], ['LUNAUSDT' , 'LUNA' ], ['MATICUSDT', 'MATIC'],
    ['NEOUSDT'  , 'NEO'  ], ['ONGUSDT'  , 'ONG'  ], ['QTUMUSDT' , 'QTUM' ], ['SHIBUSDT' , 'SHIB' ],
    ['STRAXUSDT', 'STRAX'], ['SUNUSDT'  , 'SUN'  ], ['SUSHIUSDT', 'SUSHI'], ['SXPUSDT'  , 'SXP'  ],
    ['TLMUSDT'  , 'TLM'  ], ['TRXUSDT'  , 'TRX'  ], ['XEMUSDT'  , 'XEM'  ], ['XRPUSDT'  , 'XRP'  ],
  ];
  .forEach(m => MARKETS[m[0]] = {name: m[0], shortname: m[1]});

  const s = ss.getSheetByName('History1');

  // get all data from 'History1'
  const data = s.getRange(1,1,s.getLastRow(),8).getDisplayValues();

  // get list of markets from column 2 (only unique values)
  const markets = s.getRange(2,2,s.getLastRow(),1).getValues()
  .flat().filter(String).filter((item,i,ar)=>ar.indexOf(item)==i);

  // fill all sheets with data
  markets.forEach(m => fill_sheet(MARKETS[m], data));
  
  // test:
  // console.log(markets[0]);               // show first market
  // fill_sheet(MARKETS[markets[0]], data); // fill first sheet

}

function fill_sheet(market, data) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get from data only the rows of given market
  var data = data.filter(x => x[1] == market.name);

  // go to sheet and add the rows
  const s = ss.getSheetByName(market.shortname);
  const lastRow = s.getRange('A1:A').getValues().filter(String).length;
  s.getRange(lastRow+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

}
```

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: bro, I have checked the code and also applied the same as you have written above but it is not working. It is not populating data into sheets. Can you please check it again what is missing. You can check the same google sheets which I have shared It is open to access for all. You can test on it realtime. Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried the simplest variant. In second variant it turned out you already have the global variable `SS`. I made my variable `ss` a local variable. Now it works. I just tested.

Comment: Khrishtich Thanks bro, it's working very well.

Comment: You're welcome. I shudder to think what that would be like to copy and paste all these rows manually. :)

Comment: I have automate entire process and I am getting stuck with errors and also with some rows handling. Would you like it to see on same thread or I need to open new thread?

Comment: Hi! It makes sense to open a new thread, I suppose. But I'm on vacation right now ) With no laptop at the hand. So someone else will try to help you. I'm sure

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple formula like:

```
=FILTER(History1!A:H, History1!B:B="ETHUSDT")
```

so after you paste your date into History1 sheet all will be sorted automatically in those other sheets of yours

[image]

Comment: but bro, I have new data each day and I want to keep both previous data and new data, that's why I think a script which filters data then copy and paste it on the next empty rows of the sheet would work well. any solution like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function split_history(){
  
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var hissht=ss.getSheetByName("History1");
  var hisvals=hissht.getDataRange().getValues();
  var sheets=ss.getSheets();
  for (i=0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    if (sheets[i].getName()=="Summary" || sheets[i].getName()=="History1" || sheets[i].getName()=="Main Menu" ) {} else {
      var sn=sheets[i].getName();
      var vals=[];
      for (j=1;j<hisvals.length;j++){
        if (hisvals[j][8]==sn){
          vals.push([hisvals[j][0],hisvals[j][1],hisvals[j][2],hisvals[j][3],hisvals[j][4],hisvals[j][5],hisvals[j][6],hisvals[j][7]]) ; //modify it as per your need
        }
      }
      var dsht=ss.getSheetByName(sn);
      var dlr=dsht.getLastRow();
      dsht.getRange(dlr+1,1,vals.length,8).setValues(vals); //i have used only 4 columns A,B,C,D - you can modify it

    }
  }
}
//
```